# How is jackson serializing object outside of transition

Tags: spring-boot, jackson

This is a bit bizarre for me.  My understanding is if you try to access entity outside of Hibernate session you should get an LazyInitializationException - no session, but I am not getting this exception.  In fact it seems like I still have session continue to my controller outside of my service layer which has @Transactional annotation.

**Question**

- Is this the way it should be? or there is something I didn't set up correctly?

Structure

```
       User
        | 
     Profile { hierarchies entity }
        |
  +-----+-----+
  |           |
Teacher   Student
```

User

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private Long id;
 private String firstname;
 private String lastname;

 @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY , mappedBy = "user")
 @JsonManagedReference
 @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
 private List<Profile> profiles = new ArrayList<>();
```

Service

```
@Override
@Transactional
public User getUserById(Long id) {

    Optional<User> optionalUser = userRepo.findById(id);
    User user = optionalUser.get();

    logger.info("\n User -> {}", user);
    return user;
}
```

Controller :: **Instead of thow Exception, or should return empty array.  Hibernate perform a left join**

```
@GetMapping(value="/{userId}", produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public User getUser(@PathVariable("userId") Long userId) {

    logger.info("User Controller is called");

    User user = userService.getUserById(userId);

    logger.info("User is returned -> {}", user);

    logger.info("Profiles -> {}", user.getProfiles());  // <-- Expecting this to throw LazyInitializationException

    return user;
}
```

Console

```
    018-05-31 15:17:35.462  INFO 15599 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.d.c.controller.UserController          : User Controller is called
Hibernate: 
    select
        user0_.id as id1_4_0_,
        user0_.firstname as firstnam2_4_0_,
        user0_.lastname as lastname3_4_0_ 
    from
        user user0_ 
    where
        user0_.id=?
2018-05-31 15:17:35.467  INFO 15599 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.d.c.services.UserServiceImpl           : 
 User -> 
User [id=1, firstname=Hendric, lastname=Rosenberg]
2018-05-31 15:17:35.467  INFO 15599 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.d.c.controller.UserController          : User is returned -> 
User [id=1, firstname=Hendric, lastname=Rosenberg]
Hibernate: 
    select
        profiles0_.user_id as user_id2_3_0_,
        profiles0_.id as id1_3_0_,
        profiles0_.id as id1_3_1_,
        profiles0_.user_id as user_id2_3_1_,
        profiles0_1_.citizent_id as citizent1_2_1_,
        profiles0_1_.profile_type as profile_2_2_1_,
        profiles0_2_.license as license1_1_1_,
        profiles0_2_.practitioner_type as practiti2_1_1_,
        profiles0_2_.profile_type as profile_3_1_1_,
        profiles0_2_.specialized as speciali4_1_1_,
        case 
            when profiles0_1_.id is not null then 1 
            when profiles0_2_.id is not null then 2 
            when profiles0_.id is not null then 0 
        end as clazz_1_ 
    from
        profile profiles0_ 
    left outer join
        patient profiles0_1_ 
            on profiles0_.id=profiles0_1_.id 
    left outer join
        medical_profession profiles0_2_ 
            on profiles0_.id=profiles0_2_.id 
    where
        profiles0_.user_id=?
c.d.c.controller.UserController          : User is returned -> [
 Student [profileType=STUDENT, id=A1236578889], 
 Teacher [profileType=TEACHER, license=234SFLLWEKD32342]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`spring.jpa.open-in-view = true` is set by default. So you won't get a LazyInitializationException

This property will register an [OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/support/OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor.html)

> Spring web request interceptor that binds a JPA EntityManager to the thread for the entire processing of the request. Intended for the "Open EntityManager in View" pattern, i.e. to allow for lazy loading in web views despite the original transactions already being completed.
>   This interceptor makes JPA EntityManagers available via the current thread, which will be autodetected by transaction managers. It is suitable for service layer transactions via JpaTransactionManager or JtaTransactionManager as well as for non-transactional read-only execution.
>   In contrast to OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter, this interceptor is set up in a Spring application context and can thus take advantage of bean wiring.